# Get rid of the script file that starts a jar

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have 3 files :

1. MyApp.jar
2. start.cmd
3. start.sh

Here is what's in the start files :

```
java -cp MyApp.jar -Xms256m -Xmx1024m com.companyname.launch.Launcher someArgs -DsomeParameter=true
```

As you can guess, I have to start the application by executing the correct start file, depending on the OS I'm using.

Is there a simple solution to get rid of the start files, and have only a system independent executable jar file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this from Java.

Have a `FirstMain` which doesn't depend on anything. e.g. can be run without command line arguments. This main start another java program for the same JAR starting the `RealMain` with all the command line arguments you need.

Comment: So simple. It was so obvious that I didn't even think about that. Thank you !

Comment: What about the -X parameters ? As there are intended for the JVM, there are not going to be taken into account.

Comment: @ChristopheBroeckx you can see which -X args were passed to you using JMX and you can pass as many as you want when you call yourself again.